# return a splitted long sting in a table field in django queryset

Tags: mysql, django, regex, django-queryset

I am using `mySQL` as the database of my django project. One filed of a table in this db has text values seprated by `,` like:

```
tags = "Django, MySql, C, C++, Python, Cython"
```

I need to check if there is my desired string in the above field when I am filtering query set:

this is my query:

```
my_tag = "C"
posts = Post.objects.filter(tags__icontains=my_tag).order_by('-date_created')
```

The above query also return `Cython` but I just expect `C` and that's because tags text is not splitted by `,`. How can I find a sting in a text, In regular python there is `str.split(',')` or `regex`  however in django I don't know!

Comment: Use `FIND_IN_SET(tag, tags)` as a filter.

Comment: You mean like `Post.objects.filter(FIND_IN_SET(my_tag, tags)).order_by('-date_created')`?

Comment: In SQL it is correct, but I don't know how this is looks like in django... test.

Comment: Should be something like `Post.objects.extra(where=['FIND_IN_SET(my_tag, tags)']).order_by('-date_created')`, however still is not working.

Comment: Can you say `ORDER BY x DESC` instead of `ORDER BY -x`?

Answer (score -1):

If tags = "Django, MySql, C, C++, Python, Cython" is plain text such as (models.CharField(max_length=200)) you should be able to find it by using python:

```
newtags = tags.split(',')
' C' in newtags
```

If tags is a relation to a separate model you should be able to query it with "tags__iexact"